How to have parallel jobs need different other parallel jobs in Gitlab CI/CD?
In the Gitlab pipeline configuration I am using the parallel:matrix feature for a build job configuration as well as for a deploy job. However, the different parallel jobs in the deploy job need the artifacts from different build jobs, respectively.
Namely, the

deploy:incremental [x] needs build:incremental [a]
deploy:incremental [y] needs build:incremental [a]
deploy:incremental [z] needs build:incremental [b]

This is the (reduced) build job:
build:incremental:
  extends: .build_job_base
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - BUILD_TASK: [a, b, c]

and this is the current (reduced) deploy job:
deploy:incremental:
  needs: [build:incremental]
  extends: .deploy_job_base
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:x
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile1
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore1
      - IMAGE_TAG: [$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:y, $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:z]
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2

What I want to achieve now is, that the deploy:incremental job does not depend on build:incremental as a whole, but that the parallel deploy jobs explicitly need the specified build jobs above.
I tried the following approaches, but ran into syntax errors each time:

specify when in the needs:parallel:matrix section:

deploy:incremental:
  needs:
    - job: build:incremental
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - BUILD_TASK: a
            when:
              - IMAGE_TAG: [$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:x, $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:y]
          - BUILD_TASK: b
            when:
              - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:z
  extends: .deploy_job_base
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:x
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile1
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore1
      - IMAGE_TAG: [$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:y, $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:z]
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2


parametrize the BUILD_TASK value in the parallel matrix of the deploy job:

deploy:incremental:
  needs:
    - job: build:incremental
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - BUILD_TASK: $DEPEND_ON
  extends: .deploy_job_base
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:x
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile1
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore1
        DEPEND_ON: a
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:y
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2
        DEPEND_ON: a
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:z
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2
        DEPEND_ON: b


parametrize the BUILD_TASK by specifying the full name of the parallel job

deploy:incremental:
  needs: [build:incremental $DEPEND_ON]
  extends: .deploy_job_base
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:x
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile1
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore1
        DEPEND_ON: a
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:y
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2
        DEPEND_ON: a
      - IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:z
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile2
        DOCKER_IGNORE: .dockerignore2
        DEPEND_ON: b

Now I am running out of ideas to try and fear that what I want to achieve here may not be possible, but I feel like this might be an issue encountered by others before. So maybe someone has an idea and might be able to help out

It is not currently possible to expand variables in needs:parallel:matrix.
There's an open issue in gitlab's issues https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/423553
You need to either write every job separate or generate an yml file on the fly with the variables set correctly.
